# Interstitial ads with Google ad manager

Tags: google-dfp

Since Google ad manager (former dfp) does no longer support synchronous tags, how should I run interstitial (or expandable) ads?

I've tried a template from richmediagallery ([Manzoni Intro Fullscreen](https://storage.googleapis.com/rich_media_gallery_public/templates/Manzoni_HTML5_Templates/IntroFullscreen/preview.html)) but it does not work even if I set it up with `defineOutOfPageSlot`. The iframe, inside which the ad is displayed, is always 1x1px, and it never exapnds to full screen. The template works only when displayed stand alone and not from dfp.

`Enabler.requestFullscreenExpand()` inside the ad has no effect on the parenting iframe.

How do I force iframe to expand?

Comment: did you enable your custom template for out-of-page slots in the custom template interface ?

Comment: Yes, I did try out-of-page slots, but it the end I have to use safe frame API to expand the parenting iframe.

Comment: on your custom template page, did you untick the "deliver in safeframe" button ? dis you tick the "deliver template in out-of-page" button ? Could you share a test page or the template code ?